# SQL Server Management Studio show complete content of field varchar(max)

Tags: sql, ssms

There is a way in SQL Server Management Studio to read all the contents of a `varchar(max)` column when you run a select?

I know that there is an option in `Options > Query Execution > SET TEXTSIZE`. But I was wondering if are something like when you have a XML file that you can click the cell and a new tab is open with the cell contents.

Comment: No, unfortunately, there's nothing like the XML (open in separate tab) for `varchar(max)`. You really have to use the `Options > SET TEXTSIZE` - or create an external application that reads out and displays all the contents of the `varchar(max)` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - there is no direct way to get full cell data in SSMS grid. SSMS truncates it.
But: SSMSBoost add that I develop does what you need: it allows to copy cell contents 1:1. All bytes, even if there are megabytes !
http://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-copy-results-grid-cell-contents-line-with-breaks

Comment: I installed the SSMSBoost and for copy the entire value of the cell works very well, only i don't know why but i lost the status bar color that is set for my test and production server.

Comment: Ok. Checkout preferred connections of SSMSBoost - you can configure colors there. It is more flexible as standard, as far as SSMSBoost tracks current database of editor window and changes color on the run

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried results to text?

Here's a screenshot / guide:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/19/sql-server-2005-ssms-viewsend-query-results-to-textgridfiles/

Comment: Yes but all the entire content is not show. The worst of this is that i put the max value of TEXTSIZE to 2147483647 and all the content is not showed

Comment: I guess that makes sense since you're using varchar(max)... but I've still got a trick for you: select the result and copy paste it into a notepad editor to read the whole thing.  You can do it for multiple results with excel also I believe.  Outside of that, I'm not aware of a good way to view very large text strings in SSMS.